# flexslider crashes the page in ie7 because of starting code

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, flexslider

I have used a couple of flexsliders in my project, but when I want to check the pages in ie7, there is something about the flexslider code that causes the page not to be able to finish loading and crash..

if i delete this piece of code, it works, anyone any idea whats the problem here?

```
start: function(slider) {
    $('body').removeClass('loading');
}
```

Comment: Can you share complete initialisation code for flexslider?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpvDj